# UI framework vs Styled-components to make UI from scratch in React?

Tags: reactjs

I jumped into React recently, so I'm very confused about many things. One of them is about how most of people design UI in React.

Before jumping in, I used Bootstrap to design UI of my website by using pre-made components such as buttons, modal views, navigations, and so on. But, figured out I can't use it anymore in React, but I can use `React-Bootstrap` instead. Is `React-Bootstrap` still the most popular UI framework in React as well? I'm asking that because I found some other UI frameworks such as Semantic UI or Material UI for React.

Also, I found `styled-components`. However, styled-components makes me feel like I need to make every component by myself to use which sounds like taking too long time.

As a very beginner, I'm curious about how people usually work on UI in React?

Comment: you can still use bootstrap in react without these libraries, you just need to add the correct className to you elements (buttons, link etc...). `react-bootstrap` gives you a set of components ready to use but it's not mandatory to use it. Actually if you plan to use `bootstrap 4` you may be interested in reactstrap https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap. Material UI https://material-ui.com/ is a good one, 40k stars on github...

Comment: Would there be anything like better compatibility if I use `react-boostrap` over regular `Bootstrap`? Also, I'm using Webpack. In that case, doesn't it matter that I use any of them?

Comment: Material UI and styled-components use CSS in JS vs Semantic and React-Bootstrap which take the traditional css/sass/less route.  It may seem like using styled-components or emotion means writing more components (I mean it does mean that), but you also get the benefit of breaking up your code more and you get encapsulation of the styles

Comment: it will be easier to integrate with `react-boostrap` as it will be the glue between `bootstrap` and `react`. Look at this example https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live it shows you how to show/hide a modal by passing a property to the modal, without the library you would have to do all of this logic by yourself

Comment: Numerous other responsive UI libraries around also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, There is no clear answer for the problem. In general purpose of `styled-components` not mean don't use another `ui framework`. And the companies solve the problems which is spesific with their *Engineering Team*. They have their own architecture though. But the alone programmers are choose some open source solutions.

Well, Some people use together or alone. It's totally about your project or your style of architecture. But still i would say some stuffs for giving point of view.

In the other hand; the **UI Frameworks** are solve modular problems. An example: You cannot create **a modal** with only css even `styled-components`. you know, you need JavaScript for that.

### To use both:

- You can use on Elements `Semantic-UI`(**ReactJS** or direct element with the `className`),
- You can use `styled-components` instead of *css file* for spesific part of your project. As e.g: `Main`, `Aside`, `Article`, `Post`, `TopNavigation` etc.
- If you prefer to use the `styled-components`, also you can use same components in **React Native**. (There is no css file support for **React Native**. You'll need `inline` **CSS**)
- To use only `div` instead of the *spesific component*, you'll confused after project being bigger. I would recommended you to create for each meaningful Element.
- You can combine the open source community UI parts with your own **CSS**.
- You won't need a **CSS**(**Less**, **Sass**) file when you use `styled-components`. That's mean, you'll work only on your **JS** files instead **CSS** files, so you can do dynamic things in your components. `styled-components` supports almost all **CSS** features.

### To use standalone Semantic-UI:

> *I prefer `Semantic-UI-React` instead of **ReactJS** bootstrap frameworks.*

- You cannot use the **CSS** of `Semantic-UI-React` in React Native. You should choose which is another solution or actually make your own your components architecture.
- You are ready to go with every project with `Semantic-UI-React` for web/mobile site.
- You have to learn basics of **less-lang**.
- You can change everything from your theme files which `variables`.

### Lastly,

- If you have big project or goal though; *nevertheless*, i think you should use a `UI Framework` in learning and adaptive process.
- If you are still not sure what you should do you then, you have to try all of them to find your own *architecture*.
- I think in learning process, you have to concern about **ReactJS** needs(**Redux**, **Router** etc.) before **CSS**.

---

*It's my first answer at Stackoverflow. Hopefully, the answer will help you for your concern.*

Comment: Thank you for giving me your own opinion! I'm confused about `Material Design`. I found [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/), and I thought `Materia-UI` is the best choice for me over anything else. You said there is no official supported for `Material Design`, but isn't it wrong?

Comment: Yeah. It was missing information. My bad. I guess my knowledge is expired about that. There were not official ready libraries for the ReactJS. You can check the old article http://www.gistia.com/react-material-ui-design/. That's why i confused also. But still there is no information about official library. Maybe Google choosed to support that library. I'm not sure about that. Sorry. But still it looks like a official library about compatibility now.